# Graphically represent lists

Tags: python

Is there a quick way (without the overhead of using a GUI or graphics module) to visually render 2d and 3d lists.

For example if I have a 2d array of zeros and ones, I would like to draw a black and white grid according to this array.

I am looking for a module that allows me to do these thing in simple ways. Similar to the easiness of that matplotlib allows drawing graphs.

Comment: matplotlib uses a gui. Do you mean you want to print it to the console!?

Comment: No, I just do not want to mess with gui programming myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command matshow in matplotlib displays a matrix:

```
import pylab as p
p.matshow(p.array([[0,1],[1,1]]),cmap="Greys") ; p.show()
```

This would work for 2d lists. As for 3d lists, I'm not sure I fully understand how you're planning on visualising them.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Regarding 3d, I guess that half transparent cubes and the ability to freely rotate the model would be intuitive enough, but this is too much I am asking for...

Comment: Hmm ... You could try MayaVi. The overhead in coding time would be quite large, though, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something to run on command line? If that is so, you could simply write your own little function in a very few lines. Something like this:

```
>>> matrix = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,0,1]]
>>> convert = lambda x : '■ ' if x == 1 else '□ '
>>> for row in matrix:
...     print ''.join([convert(el) for el in row])
... 
□ ■ □ 
■ ■ ■ 
□ □ ■
```

Comment: Neat - I guess the only problem is if the matrix size exceeds the line length of your terminal.